# Regular expression for string between two strings?

Tags: python, regex

Sorry, I know this is probably a duplicate but having searched for 'python regular expression match between' I haven't found anything that answers my question!

The document (which to make clear, is  a long HTML page) I'm searching has a whole bunch of strings in it (inside a JavaScript function) that look like this:

```
link: '/Hidden/SidebySideGreen/dei1=1204970159862'};
link: '/Hidden/SidebySideYellow/dei1=1204970159862'};
```

I want to extract the links (i.e. everything between quotes within these strings) - e.g. `/Hidden/SidebySideYellow/dei1=1204970159862`

To get the links, I know I need to start with:

```
re.matchall(regexp, doc_sting)
```

But what should `regexp` be?

Comment: Are you working with JSON by any chance?

Comment: Looks like JSON data with `;` instead of `,` to me (when I try to imagine the rest of the document). Python has integrated JSON support.

Comment: it's a long HTML page which contains some javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on how the rest of the string may look like. If they are all like this `link: '<URL>'};` then you can do it *very simple* using simple string manipulation:

```
myString = "link: '/Hidden/SidebySideGreen/dei1=1204970159862'};"
print( myString[7:-3] )
```

(If you just have one string with multiple lines by that, you can just split the string into lines.)

If it is a bit more complex though, using regular expressions are fine. One example that just looks for the url inside of the quotes would be:

```
myDoc = """link: '/Hidden/SidebySideGreen/dei1=1204970159862'};
link: '/Hidden/SidebySideYellow/dei1=1204970159862'};"""

print( re.findall( "'([^']+)'", myDoc ) )
```

Depending on how the whole string looks, you might have to include the `link:` as well:

```
print( re.findall( "link: '([^']+)'", myDoc ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with:

```
regexp = "'([^']+)'"
```

And check if it works okay - I mean, if the only condition is that string is in one line between '', it should be good as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use a few simple splits

```
>>> s="link: '/Hidden/SidebySideGreen/dei1=1204970159862'};"
>>> s.split("'")
['link: ', '/Hidden/SidebySideGreen/dei1=1204970159862', '};']
>>> for i in s.split("'"):
...     if "/" in i:
...         print i
...
/Hidden/SidebySideGreen/dei1=1204970159862
>>>
```